# How to check multiple conditions in a loop using Data Weave 1

Tags: mule, dataweave

**I have below sample payload, where I need below conditions to meet and get the same payload back using DW 1.0

If isOwned = true for productId = 1003
Then show newPrice = null and hasSpecialPrice = false for 1004,1002,1001,1000

If isOwned = true for productId = 1004
Then show newPrice = null and hasSpecialPrice = false for 1002,1001,1000

If isOwned = true for productId = 1002
Then show newPrice = null and hasSpecialPrice = false for 1001,1000

**

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"0.00",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1000"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1000",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"6.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1001"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1001",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"5.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1002"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1002",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":true
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"3.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1003"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1003",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"2.99",
               "newPrice":"1.99",
               "hasSpecialPrice":true,
               "productId":"1004"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1004",
         "enabled":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected Output for condition isOwned = true for productId = 1003 Then show values newPrice = null and hasSpecialPrice = false for 1004,1002,1001,1000:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"0.00",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1000"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1000",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"6.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1001"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1001",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"5.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1002"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1002",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":true
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"3.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1003"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1003",
         "enabled":null
      },
      {
         "flavors":[
            {
               "features":null,
               "entitlement":{
                  "isOwned":false
               },
               "locale":"en_US",
               "price":"2.99",
               "newPrice":null,
               "hasSpecialPrice":false,
               "productId":"1004"
            }
         ],
         "id":"1004",
         "enabled":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The conditions are unclear. Please clarify and provide examples of the expected output. By `Then show newPrice = null` do you mean to set newPrice to null in the output? What do you expect exactly as output? And what do you mean by `for 1004,1002,1001,1000`? What to do if two conditions are true?

Comment: By Then show newPrice = null do you mean to set newPrice to null in the output? Ans is Yes. What to do if two conditions are true? Ans is There is only one condition true every time. And what do you mean by for 1004,1002,1001,1000? Ans is these are productId in the payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DataWeave 1.0 you can use when/otherwise for simple conditions and pattern matching with `match` for more complex ones. To avoid putting too much logic in the main map, I created a variable that returns which of the rules is triggered and a function that updates each element. The object `updateWhich` is for identifying which elements needs to be updated based on the id triggered.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var updateWhich={
    "1002": ["1000", "1001"],
    "1003": ["1000", "1001", "1002", "1004"],
    "1004": ["1000", "1001", "1002"]
}
%var updateId=(payload.products map ( $ match {
    o when o.id == "1002" and o.flavors.entitlement.isOwned[0] -> "1002",
    o when o.id == "1003" and o.flavors.entitlement.isOwned[0] -> "1003",
    o when o.id == "1004" and o.flavors.entitlement.isOwned[0] -> "1004",
    default -> null    
  }) filter ( $ != null ))[0]  

%function updateProduct(o) o - "flavors" ++ {flavors: [o.flavors[0] - "newPrice" - "hasSpecialPrice" ++ {newPrice: null, hasSpecialPrice: false} ]}
---
products: payload.products map ( updateProduct($) when (updateWhich[updateId] != null) otherwise $)
```